# UPDATE statement on table 'xxx' expected to update 1 row(s); 2 were matched

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to update a row by sqlalchemy However I got this error.

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'ImgToolUser' expected to update 1 row(s); 2 were matched.`

I run this code.

```
user = session.query(ImageToolUser).filter(ImageToolUser.key == key).first()
user.name = 'changed'
session. commit()
```

I checked `sqlalcemy.engine log`.

```
UPDATE `ImgToolUser` SET maker=%(maker)s, effect=%(effect)s WHERE `ImgToolUser`.mail = %(ImgToolUser_mail)s
```

This query was filtered by `ImgToolUser.mail`. This table has 2 row of same `mail`. So this error message showed `2 were matched.`.

My code is filtered by `key`. However this update query is filtered by `mail`. How should I change my code for update a row?

### Solution

This question was closed. Because similar with other question. I found this questions solution. So, I'd like to share. How to solved this error.

I had mistake in ImageToolUser class.

I set `primary_key` on mail.

```
class ImageToolUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ImgToolUser"
    mail = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    key = Column(String(255))
```

I should have set it on key.

```
class ImageToolUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ImgToolUser"
    mail = Column(String(255))
    name = Column(String(255))
    key = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
```

I hope this Q&A helps for anyone.